# How to add my own folders to Favorites in Windows 10 Insider Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10-preview

This is my File Explorer:
[image]

I want to add some folders to left menu. Also, I want to remove some folders from it (e.g., OneDrive). How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried dragging your folders to Quick access?

Comment: @Karan, yep. It seems, it doesn't work.

Comment: How about right-clicking folders and selecting "Pin to Quick access"?

Comment: @Karan, oo, it works, but It works pretty weird. The result of pin folder is displayed after you pin multiple folders.

Comment: [Windows 10 Build 9926: The Quick Access Feature and Changing File Explorer's Startup Folder](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-build-9926-quick-access-feature-and-changing-file-explorers-startup-folder)

Comment: Might be a bug. Did you try refreshing Explorer (F5) after pinning a folder?

Comment: @Karan, yep, there is a bug. I cannot add folders to Favorites, which have length of name more than `8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add/remove a folder from **Quick access**:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

Batch file to remove OneDrive from the left navigation pane:

```
REG ADD "HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /V Attributes /T REG_DWORD /D 4035969101 /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Batch file to re-add OneDrive to the left navigation pane:

```
REG ADD "HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /V Attributes /T REG_DWORD /D 4034920525 /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

<sup>[Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4818-onedrive-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)</sup>

Comment: It is weird, that I can add some folder, but I cannot add another folders... For example, The Music folder adds to Favorites, but The Fake Desktop doesn't.

Comment: Might be some flags that can be modified to override that but it'll probably depend on which location you want to add. Will have to see if it's possible with the desktop.

Comment: anyway, thank you! I finally remove OneDrive and add Dropbox to the favorites.